# Using two columns with the same foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database, which has 5 tables, but I have problem. In the shipment table, there are two columns, source and destination, which are both foreign key references to the route table, but when I select a record from the shipment table it will only show the same routename for both.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT fare, commission, driver,shipment._date, routename, vehiclenumber, productname, source, destination, routename,ownername
FROM route, shipment, product, vehicle,owner
WHERE vehicle.vehicleid = shipment.vehicle
AND shipment.source
and vehicle.owner=owner.ownerid
AND shipment.destination = route.routeid
AND shipment.product = product.productid
AND vehicle.vehiclenumber =  'nk-234'
ORDER BY _date
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Can you update the SQL please? "And shipment.source" seems to end in nothing....

Comment: Learn to use the JOIN notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect a record in one table (one shipment) to more than one record in another table (two routes) you would ideally use explicit `JOIN`s against the `route` table twice (or more, for however many links you happen to need).

Here's a quick modification to your query that demonstrates usage. Pay particular attention to the two `routename` columns in the `SELECT` and the two `JOIN`s to the `route` table in the `FROM`:

```
SELECT fare,
       commission,
       driver,
       shipment._date,
       RS.routename,    <-- field from first join
       vehiclenumber,
       productname,
       source,
       destination,
       RD.routename,    <-- field from second join
       ownername

FROM shipment
JOIN route RS ON RS.routeID = shipment.source       <-- join 1; source
JOIN route RD ON RD.routeID = shipment.destination, <-- join 2; destination
     product,
     vehicle,
     owner

WHERE vehicle.vehicleid = shipment.vehicle
  AND vehicle.owner = owner.ownerid
  AND shipment.product = product.productid
  AND vehicle.vehiclenumber =  'nk-234'

ORDER BY _date

LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Obviously, this might not match your needs exactly, because I don't know what tables the other selected fields are from to be able to make sure they are all accounted for...

Comment: Strictly, you can perfectly well use `FROM route AS rs, route AS rd, ...`, but JOIN notation is better.

Comment: you don't need to use explicit joins, although I do agree that they read better.

Comment: Good point. I've toned the wording down for the sake of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you select the fields from one row in shipment, in orer to actually get any effect from your foreign keys you need to use a few joins

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the old-style (non-preferred) notation, you can write:

```
SELECT s.fare, s.commission, s.driver, s._date, v.vehiclenumber, p.productname,
       s.source, s.destination, rs.routename, rd.routename, o.ownername
  FROM route AS rs, route AS rd, shipment AS s, product AS p, vehicle AS v, owner AS o
 WHERE s.vehicleid = s.vehicle
   AND s.source = rs.routeid
   AND v.owner = o.ownerid
   AND s.destination = rd.routeid
   AND s.product = p.productid
   AND v.vehiclenumber =  'nk-234'
 ORDER BY _date
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

I had to guess which table(s) contain the fare, commission and driver information; I assumed they are all in the shipment table.

Starting a column name with an underscore is not strictly allowed in standard SQL, though most DBMS do allow it.  It looks ugly, though; why not 'ship_date' as the column name?

It is better to use the explicit join notation, not least because there is less chance of forgetting a join condition:

```
SELECT s.fare, s.commission, s.driver, s._date, v.vehiclenumber, p.productname,
       s.source, s.destination, rs.routename, rd.routename, o.ownername
  FROM shipment AS s
  JOIN route    AS rs ON s.source      = rs.routeid
  JOIN route    AS rd ON s.destination = rs.routeid
  JOIN vehicle  AS v  ON s.vehicleid   = s.vehicle
  JOIN owner    AS o  ON v.owner       = o.ownerid
  JOIN product  AS p  ON s.product     = p.productid
 WHERE v.vehiclenumber = 'nk-234'
 ORDER BY s._date
 LIMIT 0, 30
```